# MonoGame - GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.Current.Width/Height Reports wrong value on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: c#, macos, mono, monogame

I'm attempting to get the resolution of a the user's monitor using MonoDevelop/C#.

On most of the machines I've tested this on, it works flawlessly - with exception of this Macbook Pro.

Native resolution is 2880x1800, but `DefaultAdapter` width reports 1280x1024. I can manually set the graphics device `PreferredBufferHeight` and `PreferredBufferWidth`, and it's fine.

Is there a more reliable way to return the resolution of a monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reference `System.Windows.Forms` in your project, and use `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds` to find out the resolution of the user's screen.

If you have not tried using `GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Width` and `GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Height` you should probably try those first.

Yet another way is `GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width` and `GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height`.